# Jquery background position animation?

Tags: jquery

I basically have this already: http://jsfiddle.net/BnJ3G/1/ which is more or less a background animation depending on the scroll event. Similar to a paralax type function.

I basically need all the functions replicated for X and Y positions if possible, maybe something simple like this:

```
$('#element1').animatePosXY(VAL, VAL);
$('#element2').animateNegXY(VAL, VAL);
```

Etc...

I'd love the help if possible!

Answer (score 0):

Not to worry, I've been working around with it, and using the same function, I can explicitly set the background positions depending on the window Scroll, Spent over 4 hours doing it but finally got there!